# PhoneGap Android app only working on certain Android versions

Tags: android, cordova

I have Android APIs 14 through 19 installed and the androidmanifest reflects this. I ran `cordova build android` and my app is still not working on 4.0 or 4.1 (Only versions I can actively test).

Any recommendations?

Comment: Try to start it with the emulator and see if you get more specific output in the console. Also check android-minSdkVersion in config.xml

Comment: My emulator is not working - i"ve been having a ton of trouble today. The min version was 14. It was 10 early and I still had the same issue.

Comment: Without diagnosis we can not help you.

Comment: Well let me ask a different question then. If I have multiple SDKs installed, would PhoneGap automatically use them? or would it just use the newest SDK to build the application?

Comment: I was able to get the emulator working, what should I look for>